# Is there any method to identify if a loop is an "independent loop" or not?

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc

I know a loop to be independent if it contains at least one branch that is not a part of any other independent loop. But it is kind of recursion. I think it is not giving me the actual definition of independent loops (as the definition itself contains the term "independent loop"). Can anyone tell me how I can exactly define or identify an independent loop?

I learnt from a video (by EdCLAP in YouTube) that

> ***"An independent loop is a closed path within which no other closed path exists"***

Is this correct?

Edit: I saw a similar question before I posted this question. That didn't help, and I want to know how I can detect an independent loop.

EDIT2:[The associated question that seems to be duplicate but it's not](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/174335/why-are-these-independent-loops)

That question involves the formal definition and why those particular example's loops are independent. But I am trying to understand how I can exactly know a loop is independent for any circuit, not a particular one like that question. My question is generalized.

Comment: Are you referring to a circuit of some sort?

Comment: @jonathanjo no brother, I saw the question and that is why I asked it here. This recurrence of the term "independent loop" even in the definition of "independent loop" is quite confusing

Comment: I don't know what that is but I have never needed the concept. I wouldn't worry about it. Naming things just because you can doesn't necessarily mean they are useful. Seems that some authors like to do that and then confuse students.

Comment: I should say this. One independent loop means one equation with KVL. A second independent loop means also an equation with KVL. If you sum the two equations, you have a "loop" which is not independent of the others two. So one can not use it for solving.

Comment: This might be a question better asked in math.SE, because it feels more like a graph theory question than an electrical engineering question.

Answer (score 0):

> "An independent loop is a closed path within which no other closed path exists".

Answer: NO. See the two drawings of the same circuit.

As @DKNguyen pointed out in his comment, this is the point of view of a **user** of the simulation tools (mathematical and graphical).

Perhaps, check this simple example ... R4 is for "list" convenience.
Note also the "oriented" resistors (why?).

Do you recognize the **KVL independent loops**? LOOP 1, LOOP 2, or LOOP 3?
The answer is **"any Two of the three"**. Because one equation is a mix of the others 2.
NB: I forgot eq3:=E-E=0= R2 * iR2 - R3 * iR3= ...

Another point of view. How many **KCL equations** can you write?  1.
How many currents? 3.
So you need **2** KVL more equations. It is all.

[image]

Is this a "better" drawing, as @Elliot Alderson pointed out?
Is it consistent with OP question?

[image]

Comment: Your answer is not consistent with the definition provided by the OP. Loop ABCG is not independent (i.e. is not a *mesh*) because it encloses loop ABG. Only loops 1 and 3 are **independent** loops.

Comment: Op question asks if the definition provided was correct (yes, perhaps no). Mathematically (it is the goal), the point of view from the KVL equations is that **two of the three are independent**. If you take the point of view of KCL equations, you have a **star**, then you take three branches of the star at point B ... and then you complete, if necessary, with another branch to make a loop ... So, you find the two independent loops **loop1 and loop3**. Sometimes, I used the first methodology when there are dependent sources (I_of_I or I_of_V), sometimes I used the other for convenience.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson you should see my updated schematic.

Comment: Demonstrating something on a trivial example does not make it true in general.

Comment: Bof ... Just a question of "geometry" ... or "multi-dimensional graph-oriented".